# Desabilitar botão no Angular dependendo de uma variável

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um problema, tenho uma condição no angular quando a minha situação for PENDENTE, irá desabilitar dois botão.

```js
$scope.situacaoParcelaPendente = "PENDENTE";

/*ultimo teste*/
if ($scope.resultSimulacao.ticlaa1VO.dscSituacaoParcela == $scope.situacaoParcelaPendente) {
  //disabilitar btnSimular, etc
  $scope.btnSimular.disabled = true;

} else {
  //habilitar btnSimular
  $scope.btnSimular.disabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode atribuir valores boleanos a sua variável, e no seu botão no HTML você usa a propriedade [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
<input class="btn submit-btn" type="submit" value="Salva" ng-disabled="desabilitaBotao" />
```

No scopo, você atribui `true` ou `false` para a variável

```
var desabilitaBotao = $scope.resultSimulacao.ticlaa1VO.dscSituacaoParcela == 'PENDENTE';
$scope.desabilitaBotao = desabilitaBotao;
```

Sempre que o valor for `true` na tua variável, o botão será desabilitado.

Comment: Então não resolveu por que eu tenho essa variável. // $scope.btnSimular.disabled = true;

Comment: Então Pedro, eu to fazendo dessa forma abaixo, mais não ta funcionando.  $scope.situacaoParcelaPendente = "PENDENTE"; var habilitaBotao = $scope.resultSimulacao.ticlaa1VO.dscSituacaoParcela == situacaoParcelaPendente ? false : true; $scope.habilitaBotao = habilitaBotao;

Comment: Você não precisa utilizar outra variável, apenas utilize uma variável booleana na propriedade ng-disabled como citado. Tentou fazer dessa maneira?

Comment: Você está acessando a segunda variável na comparação de forma errada. Você a declarou assim `$scope.situacaoParcelaPendente` e está usando assim `situacaoParcelaPendente`.